# I am unable to hit Get method in WebAPI with umbraco project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, umbraco, umbraco7, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have trouble to hit webapi action.
I am getting 500 error in the console and the api is not reached.

This is my ajax call:

```
function getProducts() {
    var response;
    $.getJSON("/api/Product")
        .done(function (data) {
            response = $.map(data,
                function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Name + ' (' + item.Code + ')' };
                });
        });
    return response;
};
```

The ajax is not hitting. The request skips `getJson` call and returns `undefined` `response`.

This is my api controller method:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController {

    // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<ProductModel> ProductList()
        {
            ProductSearcher searcher = new ProductSearcher();
            return searcher.GetResults();
        }
    }
```

In the config I have defined:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Postman returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` but it doesn't even hit the `ProductList` either.

I have selected to run multiple projects - my app start project and web api project.

This is the error stacktrace - it looks to me like umbraco does looks for routing while I need to route to non-umbraco api:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Umbraco.Web.Routing.ContentLastChanceFinderByNotFoundHandlers.HandlePageNotFound(PublishedContentRequest docRequest) +152
   Umbraco.Web.Routing.ContentLastChanceFinderByNotFoundHandlers.TryFindContent(PublishedContentRequest docRequest) +10
   Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequestEngine.HandlePublishedContent() +529
   Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequestEngine.FindPublishedContentAndTemplate() +250
   Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequestEngine.PrepareRequest() +107
   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +361
   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule.&lt;Init&gt;b__8(Object sender, EventArgs e) +80
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +71
```

**EDIT**

I changed the routing config from `api` to `dataapi` eg. routeTemplate: `"dataapi/{controller}/{id}"` so it now runs but still throws an error:

```
405 Method not allowed
```

**EDIT 2**

Got it! Changed the method name from `ProductList` to `Get` and it's now working

Answer (score 0):

You could use an UmbracoApiController instead, to make sure that Umbraco doesn't try to match the URLs to content? Then the path to the controller would be /umbraco/api/yourcontroller instead, but everything should work the same. Take a look at https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/ for details.

Comment: Yes, I know but I don't want to use umbraco api controller as the project has no reference to umbraco and I don't want it to depend on umbraco

Comment: If the website runs on Umbraco, you are depending on Umbraco anyway, right? I guess you could try adding /api/ to reservedUrls and see if that helps, but ... my advice would still be to embrace Umbraco, it's not that dangerous :-)

Comment: No, but it's useless in this case to use umbraco just to keep the routing. The api project does not depend on umbraco. Umbraco project depends on the results from api project though. Thanks anyway - you've make me think to rename api route config.